# iOS 9, Xcode 7, Multitouch with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7-beta3

Hello I've made an iOS game named 'Racing Horses' and published it to App Store. It was fine with playing on iOS 8.x.x, but after I installed iOS 9 Beta 3, in the same game (same codes), iPhone cannot recognize multiple touches. I have to leave my finger to make the next touch. But it was not like this, I could make a new tap even if I still hold my previous tap. What is the problem, what should I do?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem on a game launched this summer.
I had to explicitly enable multiple touch in the `SKScene`:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
}
```

Here's more detail  -
The game uses sub-classes of `SKSpriteNode`.
They test for number of touches depending on the the sprite.
In the sub-class:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(@"TapCount  = %lu", (unsigned long)touches.count);

     if (touches.count == 2) {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like as of ios 9 multitouch has to be explicitly enabled. I don't think this used to be the case. I now have this issue on all my spritekit apps. Just adding self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; in viewDidLoad, fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple mistake, I've enabled multitouch at interface builder, problem solved. But I don't know how it turned off by itself :)